# Resolving CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT - No Cluster Data Available

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, corba

I have a daily job that is using a remote EJB, most of the times it works fine, but once a week it throws the following exception and fails.

> CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT 0x49421042 - No Cluster Data Available  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 42

After some research I found that this can be caused by the restart of the remote cell.

> This error is often seen for a short time when first requests for a
>   cluster are made after startup of a cell

The problem is that my scheduled job is requesting this remote EJB 10 times and all of them fail. The next time the job runs, it works fine.

HA Manager is enabled across all the JVMs, but the application that make the request is in a different core group.

How can I handle this problem? Can this exception be caused by something else?

Comment: This is a vague exception thrown by WebSphere which requires further debug. Basically, the exception is telling the client that it can not find any cluster information such the JVMs to route the request. As you stated, this could be completely normal due to numerous factors. However, to confirm, can you post the logs from the node agent that is involved? In addition, can you post the provider_URL being used by the client? I suspect you may have multiple URLs defined and perhaps one URL is no longer valid.

Comment: Why does the URL wouldn't be valid anymore? It works fine most of the times.

Comment: It could unavailable for multiple reasons such as normal shutdown or issues such as OOM or hangs. Can you post the logs from the JVM in the providerURL and the corresponding node agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have separate core groups they need to be bridged.   If they are not bridged, some parts of the cell don't have complete information which can result in "No Cluster Data Available".  See #4 on the WLM troubleshooting FAQ:  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/Troubleshooting_WLM_issues_in_WebSphere_Application_Server?lang=en